# How to have custom image and text input in ionic. Also need icon and border color change on focus

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Need a custom icon and input text which on focus must change the font color, icon, border color.

Please help.

Comment: like this `input:focus{color:red;}`

Comment: put some code here

Answer (score 1):

Updated with changing icon.

```css
input{
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  background:url(http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f512/lock.png) no-repeat right center;
  background-size:auto 100%;
}
input:focus,textarea:focus{
  color:red;
  border:1px solid red;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px red;
  background:url(http://emoji.fileformat.info/gemoji/lock.png) no-repeat right center;
  background-size:auto 100%;
}
```

```html
<input />
```

Comment: This will change only the input's border. I need the custom icon also to be changed on focus.

This is my html.

<div class="list">
 <label id="rounded" class="item item-input" > 
 <img src="img/login-icons-lock-blue.png">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password" ng-model="data.password">
 </label>
</div>

Comment: You should use css image background. - even if it's just an icon, it can be put in the pseudo element. I will update my anwser in a minute.

Comment: @Jovanna changing IMG on focus would require javascript - and that is just unnecessary - making simple things complicated.

Comment: by the way i was wrong about pseudoelement for input element. It's shortened "nonwrapping" element without any content, so `::after` `::before` pseudoelements can't be applied on them.